# Embedding a html table in an ordered list causes misalignment

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-lists

I am trying to create a reverse ordered list embedded in a table so each list item is a table row. This is so I can have a numbered table with separate columns. The following code does this but is causing an issue where the numbering is misaligned.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <body>
    <h3><b><u>2020</u></b></h3>
    <table cellpadding="6">
    <ol reversed>
        <li>
          <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: baseline;"><p>Testing</p></td>
            <td style="vertical-align: baseline;"><p>testing 2</p></td>
          </tr>
        </li>

        <li>
          <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: baseline;"><p>Testing</p></td>
            <td style="vertical-align: baseline;"><p>testing 2</p></td>
          </tr>
        </li>

        <li>
          <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: baseline;"><p>Testing</p></td>
            <td style="vertical-align: baseline;"><p>testing 2</p></td>
          </tr>
        </li>
        </ol>
        </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Compare this to the standard behavior when each cell is its own table (which I do not want)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <body>
    <h3><b><u>2020</u></b></h3>
    <ol reversed>
        <li>
          <table cellpadding="6">
          <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: baseline;"><p>Testing</p></td>
            <td style="vertical-align: baseline;"><p>testing 2</p></td>
          </tr>
          </table>
        </li>

        <li>
          <table cellpadding="6">
          <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: baseline;"><p>Testing</p></td>
            <td style="vertical-align: baseline;"><p>testing 2</p></td>
          </tr>
          </table>
        </li>

        <li>
          <table cellpadding="6">
          <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: baseline;"><p>Testing</p></td>
            <td style="vertical-align: baseline;"><p>testing 2</p></td>
          </tr>
          </table>
        </li>

        </ol>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I fix the numbering with the behavior of the first snippet? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can't mix a table and a list like that. You can have the semantics of a table or an ordered list but not a mixture. On the other hand, getting the automatic reverse numbering starting at the right number and counting down to one while complying with HTML validity is tricky. We can add styling list items as an extra cell at the start of each row like this.

```css
li {
  display: contents;
}
tr::before {
  display: list-item;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<h3><b><u>2020</u></b></h3>
<ol reversed>
  <li>
    <table cellpadding="6">
      <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;"><p>Testing</p></td>
        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;"><p>testing 2</p></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;"><p>Testing</p></td>
        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;"><p>testing 2</p></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;"><p>Testing</p></td>
        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;"><p>testing 2</p></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </li>
</ol>
```

There are [proposals for creating auto start value reversed counters](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/4211) in CSS, but no implementations yet, so we either need this rather awkward and unsemantic ol[reversed]/li wrapper or have to manually set the counter start to the number of table rows + 1, as per Mrvs's answer.

Comment: Also, you could  use a set of nth-last-child rules, with enough rules to cover all the posible number of rows. Not clean, not elegant, but doable if there is a limit to the number of rows

Answer (score 3):

**TRY THIS**

```css
table {
   counter-reset:numbers 4;
}

tr {
  counter-increment: numbers -1;
}

tr:before {
  content: counter(numbers) ". "; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <body>
    <h3><b><u>2020</u></b></h3>
    <table cellpadding="6">
          <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: baseline;"><p>Testing</p></td>
            <td style="vertical-align: baseline;"><p>testing 2</p></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: baseline;"><p>Testing</p></td>
            <td style="vertical-align: baseline;"><p>testing 2</p></td>
          </tr>


          <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: baseline;"><p>Testing</p></td>
            <td style="vertical-align: baseline;"><p>testing 2</p></td>
          </tr>

        </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `try this + code only` anwsers are considered low quality. Please explain the issue and your solution. A code snippet without explanation is in most cases nearly worthless. It doesnt help to understand the issue and makes it hard to reproduce the solution.

Comment: Hi all, can someone let me know how to include that run snippet function? I click on snippet icon on the navigation bar, then it pops up the window with what prog languages to include, how I continue from there?

Comment: @Mrvs, upvote for your CSS code to control the row counter. I learnt good from it.